# Pasar valor de un campo a otro javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html5, json

Buenas noches estimados tengo el siguiente inconveniente cuando paso un input tipo texto a otro input utilizo la siguiente forma la cual me funciona! copiando el valor del primer input al segundo input.

```
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
    <label class="label-control">T.M.H</label> <input
    type="text" class="form-control" id="tmh" name="tmh"> </div> 
                 <div class="col-md-4">
<label class="label-control">% HUM</label> <input
type="text" class="form-control" id="humedad" name="humedad" disabled>
                                    </div> 


    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tmh").keyup(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $("#humedad").val(value);
        }); }); 
  </script>
```

Pero cuando lo intento hacer lo mismo para un input tipo date o un select no funciona asi :
Ejemplo :

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="exampleInput1">Fecha</label>
                              <input  type="date" class="form-control" name="fechas" id="fechas">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="exampleInput1">Fecha2</label>
                              <input type="time" class="form-control" name="fechax" id="fechax">
                            </div>
                          </div>
 <label for="exampleInput1"> Select 1</label>
                              <select class="selectpicker" data-size="7" name="select1" id="select1" data-style="select-with-transition" title="Seleccione un tipo">
                                <option value="R"> Relave </option>
                                <option value="M"> Mineral </option>
                              
                              </select>
         <div class="col-md-4">
<label class="label-control">Select 2</label> <input
type="text" class="form-control" id="select2" name="select2" disabled>
                                    </div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#fechas").keyup(function () {
                var value = $(this).val();
                $("#fechax").val(value);
            });

    $("#select1").keyup(function () {
                var value = $(this).val();
                $("#select2").val(value);
            });


 }); 
      </script>
```

Agradezco cualquier comentario y  ayuda a trabajar mejor con javascript, gracias.
Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El  *select*  lo debes  hacer  en el evento *change* y  para igualar *fechas* a  *fechasx* ambos deben ser  del  mismo  tipo. Cambia "fechax" a  *date*.

```
  <div class="col-sm-2">
       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInput1">Fecha</label>
            <input  type="date" class="form-control" name="fechas" id="fechas">
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2">
          <div class="form-group">
               <label for="exampleInput1">Fecha2</label>
               <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fechax" id="fechax">
           </div>
    </div>
    <label for="exampleInput1"> Select 1</label>
    <select class="selectpicker" data-size="7" name="select1" id="select1" data- 
           style="select-with-transition" title="Seleccione un tipo">
                            <option value="R"> Relave </option>
                            <option value="M"> Mineral </option>
                          
     </select>
     <div class="col-md-4">
              <label class="label-control">Select 2</label> 
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="select2" name="select2" disabled>
      </div>

   <script>
           $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#fechas").keyup(function () {
                var value = $(this).val();
                  $("#fechax").val(value);
              });

          $("#select1").change(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();  // Te pintará el value de options "M"  o "R"
            // Para mostrar  el  texto de la opcion seleccionada descomenta la linea: 
          //   var value = $("#select1 option:selected").text();
            $("#select2").val(value);
        });


      }); 
  </script>
```